# How to perform check-and-insert in mysql?

Tags: mysql, multithreading, locking

In my code I need to do the following:

> Check a MySQL table (InnoDB) if a particular row (matching some criteria) exists. If it does, return it. If it doesn't, create it and then return it.

The problem I seem to have is race conditions. Every now and then two processes run so closely together, that they both check the table at the same time, don't see the row, and both insert it - thus duplicate data.

I'm reading MySQL documentation trying to come up with some way to prevent this. What I've come up so far:

- Unique indexes seem to be one option, but they're not universal (it only works when the criteria is something unique for all rows).
- Transactions even at `SERIALIZABLE` level don't protect against `INSERT`, period.
- Neither do `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE` or `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.
- A `LOCK TABLE ... WRITE` would do it, but it's a very drastic measure - other processes won't be able to read from the table, and I need to lock ALL tables that I intend to use until I unlock them.

Basically, I'd like to do either of the following:

- Prevent all `INSERT` to the table from processes other than mine, while allowing `SELECT`/`UPDATE` (this is probably impossible because it make so little sense most of the time).
- Organize some sort of manual locking. The two processes would coordinate among themselves which one gets to do the select/insert dance, while the other waits. This needs some sort of operation that waits until the lock is released. I could probably implement a spin-lock (one process repeatedly checks if the other has released the lock), but I'm afraid that it would be too resource intensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an answer myself. Transactions + `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` in an InnoDB table can provide a synchronization lock (aka mutex). Have all processes lock on a specific row in a specific table before they start their work. Then only one will be able to run at a time and the rest will wait until the first one finishes its transaction.